# Is $\frac{xy}{ x^2 +y}$ is continuous or not at $(0,0)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

I was trying to solve this question

Consider the function $\displaystyle f: \mathbb{R^2} \Rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by

$$f(x, y) =
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{xy}{x^2 + y}, x^{2} \neq -y\\
\\
0, x^2 = y
\end{cases}
$$

Then

A) directional derivative does not exist at $(0, 0)$

B) $f$ is continuous at $(0, 0)$

C) $f$ is differentiable at $(0, 0)$

D) each directional derivative exists at $(0, 0)$ but $f$ is not continuous

Checking for continuity, I tried to solve it but don't know its correct or not..[image]

Comment: Please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and type everything out: images are not searchable and handwriting can be difficult to read.

Answer (score 0):

The above question which you asked gives a plane as your solution.Therefore  no directional derivative is the answer because at any point of the given function you does not have a line or curve which gives a particular direction .

Comment: Thanks !! But the way I solved for continuity is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Your first step $|x+y|<|x^2+y|$ seems incorrect, since what if $y=-x^2$ but $x\neq 0$?

Here's a quick proof $f$ is not continuous at the origin.  Let $x\neq 0$ and $y(x)=-x^2(1+x^2)$.  Then $f(x,y(x))=\frac{1+x^2}{x}$, which blows up as $x\to 0$, even though $(x,y(x))\to (0,0)$.

Comment: That's very helpful!! How should I check Directional Derivative at (00)

Comment: Fix $a\in[0,2\pi)$ and put $x(t)=t\cos a,y(t)=t\sin a$ for $t>0$.  Then $\frac{f(x(t),y(t))-0}{t}\to 0$ as $t\to 0$.